# UCT for topological spaces with the role of cohomology and homology inversed

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In so far as homology and cohomology theories are dual, one would expect their to be an inverse UCT. By which I mean a short exact sequence which splits, with the middle term being the homology of our space with coefficients, and the two other terms involving the cohomology of our space, for example with terms like $Ext^1_R(H^n(X;R), M)$ or $H^n(X;R)\otimes_R M$.

I have tried thinking about this on my own, using the algberaic Künneth formula and the analogue "Künneth Hom" formula. Motivated namely by the hope that $Hom_R(Hom_R(R,M), M))\cong M$. This "dream" isn't even true in general (I think its true for example when $M$ is a simple $R$ module, because then $M\cong R/I$. But even assuming it to be true, I don't think this is enough.

As assuming I want to apply this to all kind of spaces, the input I would like to put into algebraic Hom Künneth formula is $Hom_R(Hom_R(S(X;R), M), M)$ (with $S(X;R)$ the singular chain complex of $X$ with coefficients in $R$). Then the problem arises pretty quickly because $S(X;R)$ is usually an infinite direct sum of copies of $R$ in which case my "dream" is definitely false in general.

And so my question, is there a version of an "inverse UCT" as I am hoping? My guess on what I have done so far is that no, except in very specific situation. The biggest situation where I think this can be recovered is on the category of CW complexes with finitely many cells in each dimension and by taking $M$ to be simple. But can anyone do better?

For reference the, I learnt homological algebra from Weibel's book. That is to say I know the Künneth formula to understand the homology of a tensor of chain complexes and of the Hom complex of two complexes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you'll find a version of this "reverse" UCT in Spanier's book; I don't know if it will be the version you want.

Comment: You  "dream" about morphisms has $R$ and $M$ mixed up.

Comment: @LeeMosher I went to go check it out, and he got the same algberiac result, but doesn't discuss what the largest space where this can be applied is. But thanks for the tip nonetheless

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Really? I get for $M$ a simple $R$ module $Hom_R(Hom_R(R,M), M)\cong Hom_R(M,M)\cong R$. With the first iso from the fact that $R$ represents the identity on $R$ modules. And the second from the fact that $M$ is simple.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a simple $\mathbb{Z}$ module. And I am not in any way claiming that changing $R$ and $M$ will make it work for simple modules, but at least it will work for free modules.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Oh yeah... I am a bit embaressed by my mistake

Comment: There are quite a lot of variants on the theme of UCT and Kunneth. It would definitely help to show us which ones you *do* know so that we can point out any ones that you don't know :). I have recently done a good deal of research on the most general rigorous conditions needed to expect these formulas to hold and to split and to split naturally etc. so it may also be the case we could point out generalisations of the things you already know. Spanier's book is quite good for these. He doesn't have all the generality but he has most of it! (*Although*, keep in mind he relies on working in a pid)